# How to Generate Logout Processing Method

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, logout

I'm trying to create a method to process logout operation in spring security.

Also I'm trying to do this `without overriding the configure() method`in SecurityConfig.

**LoginController**

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/logout")
    public String logoutDo(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
        if (session != null) {
            session.invalidate();
        }
        for (Cookie cookie : request.getCookies()) {
            cookie.setMaxAge(0);
        }
    // update database here
        return "logout";
    }
}
```

**homepage.jsp**

```
     <c:url var="logoutUrl" value="/logout" />
     <a href="${logoutUrl}">Logout</a>
```

**Project Structure**

[image: project structure]

**Output after I clicked logout link**

[image: error view]

I want to find out why logoutDo() method doesn't get executed after clicking the `logout link`.

Is there any default logout process overriding this process?

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logout is [handled by a filter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/logout/LogoutFilter.java#L111-L113), and if invoked, ends the filter chain and returns a response (typically a redirect)

This is being done by the [LogoutSuccessHandler](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/logout/LogoutFilter.java#L111)

An excerpt from Spring Security's LogoutFilter

```java
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

    if (requiresLogout(request, response)) {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Logging out user '" + auth
                    + "' and transferring to logout destination");
        }

        this.handler.logout(request, response, auth);

        logoutSuccessHandler.onLogoutSuccess(request, response, auth);

        return;
    }

    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

That being said, you can always disable Spring Security's logout functionality

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .logout()
                .disable()
        ;
    }

}
```